# Add a quick icon in Joomla 3

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla3.1

Anyone know how to add a quick icon or maybe even edit the current list of quick icons in Joomla 3.1?  To be more specific, that would be the series of links that appear on the right side of the screen immediately after logging in to Joomla admin.   I searched and couldn't find this question on stackoverflow.

Comment: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/administration/extensions-quickicons/22794

Comment: I was hoping to find a solution that didn't require installation of an extension?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go to the following file:

```
administrator/modules/mod_quickicon/helper.php
```

You will see on the start of **line 51**, arrays such as the following:

```
array(
    'link' => JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_content&task=article.add'),
    'image' => 'file-add',
    'icon' => 'header/icon-48-article-add.png',
    'text' => JText::_('MOD_QUICKICON_ADD_NEW_ARTICLE'),
    'access' => array('core.manage', 'com_content', 'core.create', 'com_content', )
)
```

- Line 1, is the link.
- Line 2, go to `media/jui/css/icomoon.css` to see what is available.
- Line 3, I'm not actually too sure about but will update when I do.
- Line 4, is the text such as Add New Article, but as you can see
  above, it's a language string
- Line 5 is the text you see such as "Add New Article", but in the code above, it's a language string

Hope this helps

Comment: I think 'icon' (line 3) is the icon that would display if the icons were bigger, like they were in the default admin theme of previous versions of Joomla before v.3.  I found these icons in the folder administrator\templates\hathor\images\header.  For 'text' (line 4), I used JText::_('Whatever text you want') as the value and it worked for me.  For 'access' (line 5), just a note - you can also just put true as the value instead of an array of 'access' values.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Also what helped me with 'image' is I downloaded/installed the icons font in TTF at yoursite.com/media/jui/fonts/IcoMoon.ttf and viewed all the choices in Character Map (Windows accessory).  You can compare each character's code at the bottom of the Character Map window with the settings in the icomoon.css file.

Answer (score 5):

QuickIcon's are actually a plug-in.

If you go to `Extensions->Plug-in Manager->Plug-ins` and select `quickicon` from the **Type** filter menu on the left you will see the any QuickIcon plugins you have installed. The default plug-ins are for Update Notifications (one for Joomla and another for Extensions).

If you are creating on as a simple short-cut to existing functionality then you're best of using one of the [QuickIcon extensions](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/administration/extensions-quickicons) on the [Joomla Extension Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/) that do that already. If you're wanting to create a QuickIcon for a custom component you're creating you will need to create your own plug-in.

You can [read about Plug-ins here](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin_Development), note that for 3.x there isn't much difference from 2.5.x plugins.

A QuickIcon plug-in consists of several files:

1. pluginname.php
2. pluginname.xml
3. various media files (images, css, js)

While the #3 is optional most plugins will use one or more of them.

If you're going to create your own plug-in I would start by looking at the two notification QuickIcon plugins that ship with Joomla 3.x. You can find them in the `/plugins/quickicon/` directory with corresponding media in `/media/plg_quickicon_*`.  As they ship with the core their CSS is in the admin templates CSS' e.g. if you using `Isis` you will find it in `/administrator/templates/isis/css/template.css`

Comment: There are only 3 Quickicons that are a plugins, primarily cause they use Ajax. The rest come from a module

Answer (score 4):

Here is the standard solution:

Copy the file `default.php` from

```
/administrator/modules/mod_quickicon/tmpl/
```

to

```
/administrator/templates/YOUR_CURRENT_ADMIN_TEMPLATE/html/mod_quickicon/
```

and open the copied file. Replace this line

```
$html = JHtml::_('links.linksgroups', ModQuickIconHelper::groupButtons($buttons));
```

with these lines:

```
$myLinks = array(
    'COM_YOUR_COMPONENT_QUICKICON_YOUR_GROUP' => array(
        array(
            'link' => JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_YOUR_COMPONENT'),
            'image' => 'pictures',
            'icon' => 'header/icon-48-article-add.png',
            'text' => JText::_('COM_YOUR_COMPONENT_QUICKICON_YOUR_ITEM'),
            'access' => array('core.manage', 'com_YOUR_COMPONENT'),
            'group' => 'COM_YOUR_COMPONENT_QUICKICON_YOUR_GROUP'
        ),
    )
);

$array = ModQuickIconHelper::groupButtons($buttons);
$array = array_merge($myLinks, $array);

$html = JHtml::_('links.linksgroups', $array);
```

For languages, use overrides like this:

```
/administrator/language/overrides/en-GB.override.ini
```

Answer (score 1):

Quickicons can be added easily using plugin in Joomla 3.x and Joomla 2.5

This plugins can be used as an example https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/tree/staging/plugins/quickicon/joomlaupdate