# Joomla 3 Quick Icon link - open in new window?

Tags: joomla3.0, joomla3.1

I have added a few links to the "Quick Icons" column on the right that appears on the page after you log in to Joomla (version 3).

Is there a way to make a quick icon open in a new window when clicked?

Comment: How did you add the icons? It looks like the layout accepts a `target` attribute, but I'm not sure if your method allows you to set it

Comment: See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17664824/add-a-quick-icon-in-joomla-3